# Generate count stats by hour, day, month and year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table a model View:

```
View(id: integer, created_at: datetime)
```

I'd like to generate view counts per **hour, day, month or year** within a period of time to use them on charts. I'm already doing something like:

```
View.group('DATE(views.created_at)')
    .select("*, count(*) AS series_count, DATE(views.created_at) AS series_time")
    .where(:created_at => (Time.now-7.days)..Time.now)
```

This results in:

```
2012-06-16 => 20
2012-06-17 => 12
2012-06-18 => 15
2012-06-20 => 38 # Issue: Didn't include a day with no records
2012-06-21 => 11
2012-06-22 => 76
```

1. The first problem is that it doesn't add padding to subtitute days or months or whatever without records.
2. The second problem is that sometimes it adds another day resulting in 8 days!
3. The third problem is it gets really tricky when i try to display counts per hour and other time cycles, Can somebody suggest a better solution that works for other than day cycles too?

Basically i'm making a module Timeline that gets included in all models for easy stats generation like:

```
include Timeline # on the model
Model.timeline(
      :time_column => :created_at,
      :period => (Time.now-24.hours)..Time.now,
      :by => :hours
    )
```

Thanks!

Comment: please specify your DBMS. Is it postgres?

Answer (score 0):

1) There's many ways to fix this problem, but I'm unsure which is more efficient. All of them include first making an array of the dates you want to show and then either adding what's not in your resulting subset or inserting what you got from the database into your map. I made something similar to make the array of expected time a while back:

```
class Time

  #Period is the number of seconds between each interval 
  def upto(end_time, period)

    division_count = (end_time.to_i - self.to_i) / period

    divisions = division_count.times.map { |div| self + (period * div) }

    divisions << end_time

  end

  #Period is the number of seconds between each interval 
  def downto(start_time, period)

    division_count = (self.to_i - start_time.to_i) / period

    divisions = division_count.times.map { |div| start_time + (period * div) }
    divisions

  end

end
```

To get an array of days between two days, call it as follows:

```
time_one.upto(time_two, 1.day.to_i)
```

WARNING: This will include both days. To have a 7 day range, remove a day from time_two.

```
time_one.upto(time_two - 1.day, 1.day.to_i
```

2) This problem is that you're taking current time instead of the last hour. You need to go back to the last day/hour/minute and then subtract from it. For a range between days, you could do like this for the month of April 2012:

```
Time.utc(2012, 04)..Time.utc(2012, 05)
```

This will get from midnight on the first day of April to midnight at the last day of april. Effectively getting all the data for that month. You can do this for years by just removing the month argument and for days by adding the day argument. [See usage here.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-c-utc)

For hours it's a bit more complicated. You could just make a new date and only transfer what you want to keep to the new date, thus stripping what you don't need, then subtract from that.

3) It's been a while since I've done SQL, so I can't really give you the exact code for this, but you could always try to format your date output so it includes hours/minutes/etc so when it groups it, it'll know. Even formatting it as a string would work. A less efficient way would be to make a separate call for each time range.

Comment: Thanks for this, The issue is that this might not work with monthly cycles because obviously months can have 28, 29, 30, or 31 days.

Comment: As I said in part 3, if you can only get just the month in your field, it'll group by month. I'll edit 2 to reflect what I meant after the code.

Comment: Also `(Date.today.to_time - 7.days)..Date.today.to_time` still returns 8 days with `Time.upto`. It used: `2012-07-10 00:00:00 +0100..2012-07-17 00:00:00 +0100`

Comment: Yes, that was the intention of the my extension. You can easily change it to your needs or follow the warning edit for clarification.